# Sorting in tag search in the Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, android-app, sorting

Whenever I search for a tag in the Android app, I have to manually switch the sorting order from `Relevant` to `Newest`. I honestly never use `Relevant`.

Wouldn't it be a better idea to either display the newest at the top by default, as on the website, or at least save which sorting the user has chosen and restore it for subsequent searches?

Comment: Well, people searching for answers use relevant

Comment: Yes, but if you seach for a tag, e.g. `Android`, you won't be looking for answers, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 1.0.12 currently propagating out on Google's servers the application remembers your last sort option and defaults to it, which should fix your issue.